# Using bits of sample code/other peoples code on dissertation

Tags: licensing

I am writing a dissertation for university final year.
I want to put a large amount of source code on a DVD for the appendix.
95% of code is written by me, but some code is copy and pasted from samples and taken from forums.

Do I have to label each bit of code that is not mine or something?
What would I write if I don't know who's code it is anymore?

Comment: Ask your advisor what he thinks is appropriate.

Comment: I can only underline the comment by hammar. There might be regulations in your university how this has to be done in your dissertation and your advisor should know them.

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely cite your source if the source specified you do so.  However, if you are taking samples and adapting them to your environment you usually don't have to cite it (as long as it has changed in a significant way).

Usually, I try to include a comment in my code if I just copy and paste something, even if it is free and open to copy.  However, this is more of a preference than a specification.

In the end, it is up to the people you got the code from (if they specified a license for the code) and your advisor at the university.